# Tkinter - open "Start" with recent files as in Windows file explorer

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Opening the windows "recent" folder with tkinter like so

```py
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
from pathlib import Path
import os

appdata = Path(os.getenv("APPDATA"))  # type: ignore
recent = appdata / "Microsoft" / "Windows" / "Recent"
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
res = Path(
    filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir=recent,
        defaultextension="*.txt",
        filetypes=(("txt file", "*.txt"), ("all", "*.*")),
    )
)
```

will not result in a filtered list of recent files. Since this windows folder contains links only (.lnk).

What would be the best way to obtain a file open dialog with a list of recent files filtered for a certain file type on a windows machine?

Comment: You cannot get such a list as Microsoft only provides the links. To get the path of the actual filoe you need to use the [IShellLink interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishelllinka). I am not sure if that is available in the pywin32 package.